# Is it wise to accept compensation in alternative currency?

Tags: compensation

Given the current hype with [Bitcoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin), I was wondering if it would be wise to accept compensation in alternative currencies? Are there any concerns to consider?

Comment: Are you proposing that your salary is set at (say) 1000 Bitcoin per year? Or are you suggesting that your employer sometimes, when you agree, pay you the Bitcoin equivalent of your dollar salary?

Comment: Good point. Let's operate with that presumption in mind. But given the multitude of compensation packages available, vacation-days, company matching, flex hours, remote work, on-call, what is the viability and value of alternative currencies? On that note, would this question be a good fit for the Workplace in the first place? I am starting to think not.

Comment: @FrankFYC this SE does deal with compensation issues; heck, we have a whole tag for it ... I'm thinking there's some room for this kind of Q.  If for no other reason, so we can beg you not to take Bitcoin as compensation...

Comment: @DJClayworth in a fixed contract like that, I am sure that the company would have renegotiated the terms, as 1K BTC is ~$7,000,000 right now. Most likely, the terms would have been $X in BTC based on market rates (which would be fair, but extremely volatile, making estimating payroll budgets effectively useless).

Comment: @akaioi No plans, just curiosity.

Comment: You can get paid in whatever you can legally get paid in and get your employer to agree to pay you in. If your employer pays you your dollar salary equivalent, would this be any different from just buying it yourself (minus possible tax differences)? If you agree on a fixed amount of Bitcoin at some interval, it would of course be a gamble on both of your parts, but people do gamble, so... I'd be inclined to say this seems more like a question that discusses the validity of Bitcoin as a currency and speculation on it's future value - that's more of an opinion-based finance question.

Comment: Would make for some interesting conversations with the tax office. In the UK for example, there is income tax to be paid, National Insurance contributions for employer and employee, pension contributions. And all the calculations are based on British Pound.

Comment: Despite its definition, bitcoin is not really a currency at this point in time. It is a vehicle for speculative investment thrill-rides. If you put a bitcoin in your pocket in the morning, you almost have no idea what value it will have when you pull it out of your pocket in the afternoon. Bitcoin could crash at any time. It has its place in a well-diversified portfolio but it is wholly infeasible as a medium to exchange goods and services (with few exceptions).

Comment: Final CV cast. I believe this is potentially more a [money.se] topic but even there it's probably not a great question. Real problem here is that you have no practical goal here. An academic discussion of this topic is beyond our scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the thing ...

Bitcoins may or may not be the cat's meow.  That requires a lot of research and thought.  So why not leave your options open?  That is, get paid in traditional currency, and then you can decide whether or not to buy Bitcoin on your own time.  If your contract with employer says you get paid (fully or partially) in Bitcoin, it's a lot harder to change your mind, because now employer has to take action as well.

Note that this applies to *any* non-traditional payment -- gold, apples, what have you.  Unless employer somehow has a huge discount on the non-traditional payment he's offering you (think healthcare!), it's almost always better to take payment in cash and deploy the cash as you will.

Comment: The conceptual issue here is that, if one BTC is $7000 and it is $7500 tomorrow. The company would have "lost out" on potentially $500 in value if they sold the BTC at market instead of compensating their employees in BTC. The inverse holds true as well, if the price went down, the company just paid their employee at a discount. Vice-versa from the employee's perspective.

Comment: As for "huge discount" an early adopter would effectively leveraged their initial investment of X at time A, to X*(Appreciation Value at time B). Essentially costing the company $X, yet deriving X*(Appreciation Value at time B) in terms of labor from the employee.

Comment: The closest situation I can think of is where a company "compensates" its employees in stock that is valued at X at time A, but appreciates/depreciates to Y at time B. If the company does well the former, if poorly the latter. The total cost of company however, is based upon the market value of a potentially-unlimited (to my knowledge, there isn't a upper limit on total shares outstanding for a company) unknown-quantity (decisions to increase total shares is decided by the company)  'share' not a limited known quantity: BTC.

Comment: But I know of no instance where someone is compensated purely in the form of stock.

Comment: @FrankFYC here's an interesting article which posits that paying in stock is more expensive than paying in cash (for the company):  https://law.utexas.edu/faculty/calvinjohnson/STOCKCOM.pdf  Worth a look-see...

Comment: @FrankFYC let me also suggest that while it's possible that the variance in bitcoin values may increase or decrease the company's effective price for paying you, from your point of view it almost doesn't matter if they're paying you at a predetermined rate.  That is, if they're paying you 100 bitcoin/month, that's what you get, and it's their problem if the price went up or down after they bought it.  If they propose to pay you $X **worth** of bitcoin/month, *then* it gets interesting...

Comment: But it's silly to be paid "$X worth of Y" because your salary is still in $ except you're being paid with something else. At that point, why not just get paid $ and buy BC yourself? Why get the employer involved at all?

Comment: @Erik from employee's point of view, that's true, and that's the advice in the actual answer.  The "interesting" part is how, depending on when and at what price bitcoins are bought, paying employees in bitcoins may be way cheaper or way more expensive than anticipated.  And probably one of the several reasons most companies don't do that...

Comment: My thoughts exactly on LinkedIn.

Comment: @FrankFYC stock is effectively fiat currency issued by your employer.

Comment: @akaioi if the employer receives most of its revenue in bitcoin then the most convenient way to pay its employees would also be in bitcoin.

Comment: There is a tangible advantage in getting paid in crypto - if you are a very remote worker, mostly when working contract. Simply because there are scnearios wher emoney transfer turns into an issue - and it is a non issue in crypto. That said, this is contractors - employees would in this case run through an umbrella contracted by the employer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two key issues with "alternative" currency:

- **Acceptance**: Getting paid for my work is not the end by itself. If places where I want to *spend* that money doesn't accept it, it is worthless garbage. I cannot use bitcoins to pay off my home loan, buy groceries, invest in stock market, buy movie tickets, fill my fuel tank, etc.
- **Security**: If one fine day, someone pulls the plug on bitcoin, I lose all my money. This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as government interference or software bugs. By contrast, value of the money paid to me in "real" currency is guaranteed (ignoring inflation) unless the State that issued the currency withdraws it or gets destroyed (both of which are close to impossible scenarios, at least in my case).

As a result, I will have to convert bitcoins into my "home" currency anyway. Getting paid in "alternative" currency is thus a *nuisance* that I would keep out of my life at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a bitcoin expert.  I am paid in USD and I prefer that (but in conceding my lack of expertise I remain open to the possibility that I am ignorantly acting against my own self-interest).

However, bitcoin is clearly superior to many third world fiat currencies - especially North Korean Won, Zimbabwe Dollar, Venezuala Peso.  Even if you live in those countries you do not want to accept that currency if you can help it.

Comment: But that is not employment. Employment often has legal ramifications (social security payments the employer has to do) so that he either would have a subsidiary locally, or hire through an umbrella (that then handles payroll in a country for the few employees there).

Comment: Last paragraph is correct, I go to a LOT of trouble not to be paid in the local currency, because it's useless anywhere else. Plus as with most third world currency's the buying and selling rate are so different that you lose a huge amount if you have to transfer money overseas. If I travel I have to change it to USD or something else, because most countries do not even change my currency.

Comment: @TomTom it is hard for me to imagine a future in which I am in North Korea selling my time and effort for money, but it is even harder to imagine me in North Korea selling my time and effort for North Korean Won.

Answer (score -3):

This already happens, many consultants get paid exclusively by paypal, there is no real difference, it's just another form of fiat currency, you risk it all falling to bits, but that can happen with any fiat currency.

It would be pretty specialised work to do the payroll etc,. but it could be done.

In many countries ANY currency is preferable to the local one.

Comment: I might be mistaken but paypal is just a means of transferring money.  Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies are not fiat currency.  If you accept USD (whether in paper form or electronically via paypal) then at some level you trust the United States government - including Trump.  If you accept bitcoin then you are not trusting anything but the strength of the underlying cryptographic process.

Comment: @emory yeah in theory, in practice no money gets transferred just a bunch of numbers on computer.

Comment: Bits on a computer declared to be legal tender by the goverment is different.

Comment: It's only different if bitcoin goes bust,....

Comment: @Kilisi That would be outside "no real difference".   It is not limited to bust but also a legal issue on like sue for back pay.

Comment: @Kilisi I am not going to say that you should trust the cryptographic claims, but if you do trust them then you do not have to worry about counterfeit currency or transfer reversals or corrupt politicians.

Comment: @emory or paying tax (if you do it properly) ;)